# Angular ng-repeat but different directives within the repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to use `ng-repeat` in angular to repeat a bunch of `<li>` with a directive inside. However, I want the two first items in the `ng-repeat` to have different styling and html changes than the rest. I was thinking of using `ng-class` to take in a function that sets specific classes based on the $index of the `ng-repeat`, to solve the css part of the problem. However, for the html changes, all I can think of is having `ng-shows`/`ng-hides` for parts within the repeated directive that are set based on the `$index` being equal to 0 or 1.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

I want to always have the two first items of the `ng-repeat` be present, and to be different styles (from each other and the other items in the list), and they must use `ng-repeat` (because of animation goals).

```
<ul class="wrapper">
     <li ng-class="conTroller.function(item.id)" id="Example2{{$index}}" ng-repeat="item in conTroller.list track by $index">
          <directive id="Example{{$index}}"></directive>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Code is of the HTML where the `ng-repeat` is called (with psuedo names). Typescript is being used. Code is just shown for aid, mostly what I need help with is the concept itself.

Comment: You can add an attribute for your directive to like index="{{$index}}" and in your directive link function add some logic to make this happen.

Comment: I don't think your approach is all that bad.  Might be a little more straightforward to evaluate index in an ng-switch which is preferred for swapping DOM elements based on some criteria rather than using ng-show/ng-hide

Comment: I was thinking of using ng-switch, but to my understanding it hides the item when the switch condition is not met, which is not the intended behaviour I want for the first two items. 

@Rob could you please expand on the directive link function part, specifically how it would use the attribute.

Comment: @Shawn123 I created a quick fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tc580w2o/ which I think is a start to what you're looking for if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @Rob Thanks! Is there a way for {{content}} to instead be html?

Comment: @Shawn123 yes.  You can just set what you need in the link function in the directive.

Answer (score 1):

You could completely change the HTML template based on properties set on the DOM element that the directive was applied to.

In the directive({}) object, set templateUrl to a function and return a string of which template to use reading the element's attribute values.

More information:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-

Hope this helps,

thanks,
Shane